# How to handle the "paste" event in Android 3.0(Honeycomb)?

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, android-3.0-honeycomb, paste

I have a customized EditText, which need to do customized "paste".

I overrode onTextContextMenuItem(int id) to handle "paste" requested by selecting context menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(int id) {
  switch(id){
  case android.R.id.paste:
    doMyPaste();
    return true;
  }
}
```

This works in Android before 3.0.
In 3.0, however, there is a small "paste" widget near the cursor widget if it's long-pressed, or the cursor is tapped.
[image]
When user do "paste" from this widget, the `onTextContextMenuItem(int id)` won't be invoked. As a result, I can't do the customized paste.
Do any one knows what that small "paste" widget is? Which method should I overrode to do a my own "paste"?

Comment: do you wish to make like clipboard funda? then this is for U.    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But in my app, I need to insert some ImageSpan into my customized Note object, not directly insert into the customized EditText. So ClipboardManager doesn't help.  I know there is a "modern clipboard" which can copy/paste complicated contents, but that doesn't work for older android. For compatibility, I have to implement my own copy/paste.

Comment: Not sure what you mean in your comment, sounds like a combination of these classes { ClipData, ClipData.Item } would solve your problem. It would be interesting to see how you solve this, if you don't mind, post your solution!

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/clipboard/copy-paste.html

Comment: Given that BGS and ProfSmiles suggest solutions on honeycomb that aren't backward compatible, maybe consider using those on honeycomb and disabling on older platforms?

Comment: Thanks entropy for the good idea. At last my app show it's own "paste" button, and stop passing the TouchEvent to super.dispatchTouchEvent, so that the "paste" from system never show. I know it's a stupid solution, but it's simple, and works for me. Other people who may search this post, should follow entropy's suggestion. I am a bad man, don't learn from me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cover all bases, this has to be API-specific, so you must commit to doing it two different ways anyway.

For new APIs, the new `android.content.ClipboardManager` interface provides everything you need to transfer any MIME type you want.

For old APIs, you must be tricksy if you expect to play with the old `android.text.ClipboardManager`.  Just base-64 encode the data of your Image (or whatever) and send that as text.  On the receiving side, just reverse the process.

You can even "auto-detect" by determining whether you have `android.text.ClipboardManager` or `android.content.ClipboardManager` and act accordingly!

Also, your handler method should be returning `super.onTextContextMenuItem(id)` if you don't process anything.  Maybe an editing artifact?

As far as the Paste Widget, that's not present in old APIs, or may be present on certain OEM UIs, and you are probably left with implementing that yourself, or using a degraded method of interaction.  Once you put text on the clipboard, the Paste command shows up in the "normal" context menus.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, the base64 idea is great!

Answer (score 0):

**call past event inside afterTextChanged() method check now**

```
editBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // do with text
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // do with text
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "call past", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```